# NDSEG Eligibility Confusion

Tags: funding

I'm pretty sure I'm eligible to apply for the NDSEG fellowship however some wording across their various pages seems somewhat vague and slightly outdated. I'm applying for grad school this fall to start a master's program in fall 2024, and I do intend to do a PhD. To me, it seems that they're now accepting applications for those either in a master's or doctoral program but that wasn't always the case. Can someone confirm that I am eligible to apply to the NDSEG even though I'm applying for a master's?